# Create Array Of Class In Typescript

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

How can I create array of class and then push some classes in it , I just have to create same as

**In C#**

```
 public class CheckBoxListItem
{        
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }         
}

List<CheckBoxListItem> cbx = new List<CheckBoxListItem>();
cbx.Add(new CheckBoxListItem(){DisplayName ="ABC",Value="NOW",IsChecked=true});
```

**In Typescript**

```
class Graph{
graphType:string;
checkedItems:CheckBoxListItem[];
}


 class CheckBoxListItem
 {
  DisplayName: string  
  Value:string  
  IsChecked:boolean
 }
```

**Properties**

```
  checksGraph :CheckBoxListItem;
  graphModel:Graph;
```

**Constructor**

```
constructor(private el:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer) { 


  this.checksGraph = new CheckBoxListItem();
  this.graphModel = new Graph();
}
```

**Problem**

```
  pushItem(){

    this.checksGraph.DisplayName=displayName;
    this.checksGraph.Value=value;
    this.checksGraph.IsChecked=check;      
    this.graphModel.checkedItems.push(this.checksGraph); 
 }
```

This line could not run becuase checkedItems is undefined

> this.graphModel.checkedItems.push(this.checksGraph);

also cannot use

> this.graphModel.checkedItems = new CheckBoxListItem[50];

this throws TypeError: CheckBoxListItem[50] is not a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Graph` class definition, change

`checkedItems:CheckBoxListItem[];`

to

`checkedItems:CheckBoxListItem[] = [];`

Comment: Do I need to initialize the property inside constructor after this?

Comment: when I push some class all previous elements copies the same